# in triangle abc the measure of angle b is 90o ac is 50o and bc is 14o which ratio represents the tangent of angle a

Tags: trigonometry

Need help answering this question. in triangle abc the measure of angle b is 90o ac is 50o and bc is 14o which ratio represents the tangent of angle a

Comment: Do you know the definition of tangent in a right-angled triangle like this one? How about sine and cosine?

Comment: Do you mean the angles are 90, 50, and 40?

Comment: You have angles $b$, $ac$ and $bc$? This doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a right triangle, you can use the pythagorean theorem to find side ab .

$ab^2+bc^2=ac^2$

$ab^2=500^2-140^2$.

Tangent is opposite over adjacent, so it would be $\frac{bc}{ab}$.